# Add Flash player to WEBVIEW (android)

Tags: android, flash, webview

I'm working on my new "app" and I have a problem when I'm trying to show videos into my app (webview) but I got this message:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1rEM.png

How to solve it??
Thanks all!

Comment: Have you tried running the app on any other device?

Comment: android:hardwareAccelerated="true" is added in your manifest?

Comment: @vishal I think no...where I need to put it?


`<activity        android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="DroidWebViewActivity">
        </activity>`
?

Comment: It must be placed under <application> tag.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html

Comment: Nice!
now I got this ERROR:
**Description Resource Path Location Type
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android' AndroidManifest.xml /DroidWebView line 15 Android AAPT Problem**

Comment: Post your activity and manifest code.

Comment: setPluginState () has been deprecated since API 18.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setPluginState%28android.webkit.WebSettings.PluginState%29

Comment: I change the API to 17. Everything is good ...but i'm still see the flash message.. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/p1rEM.png) 
attached my ManiFest....

Comment: @vishal What do you think?

Comment: The image has a button sating "Get Flash Player". Tried clicking on that? What does it do?

Comment: Hi, I got this message: 
http://postimg.org/image/ivl7rwy0l/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pskpartha.droidwebview"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        >
        <activity
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:configChanges="touchscreen|keyboardHidden|orientation"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:name="DroidWebViewActivity"
            >
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps on this link to manually install Flash Player on your device : https://forums.adobe.com/thread/1061194?tstart=0